# Error whilst creating ACL on Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, acl

So I´m running zookeeper and kafka on the same machine, I´ve modified the server.properties file as the following

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# This configuration file is intended for use in ZK-based mode, where Apache ZooKeeper is required.
# See kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults
#

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.88:9092

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.88:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

# Enables ACL authorizer by configuring class name
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer

############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
#log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

# Grant permissions to the Kafka admin user
superUser=User:*;

# Allow all clients to connect to the broker
User:*;Host:*,Permission:allow,Operation:All;

# Grant read and write permissions to a specific topic
Topic:test-topic,PermissionType:Allow,Principal:User:test-user,Operation:Read,Write;
```

So when i try add a ACL with this command for example:

> sudo /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.88:9092 --add --allow-principal User:producer --allow-host 10.20.20.33 --operation write --topic test

I get this crash message:

```
Adding ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=TOPIC, name=test, patternType=LITERAL)`:
        (principal=User:producer, host=10.20.20.33, operation=WRITE, permissionType=ALLOW)

Error while executing ACL command: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createAcls
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createAcls
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.$anonfun$addAcls$3(AclCommand.scala:115)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:985)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:193)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:984)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.$anonfun$addAcls$1(AclCommand.scala:112)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$AdminClientService.addAcls(AclCommand.scala:111)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand$.main(AclCommand.scala:73)
        at kafka.admin.AclCommand.main(AclCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createAcls
```

It seems aswell that i cant even describe the topic that I created earlier after I added the "authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer" line to the server.properties file. Everything worked fine before this and I was able to stream data without any authorization, but I can´t seem to find the issue about this line and every guide that I could find have the exact same line.

I´ve checked that kafka and zookeeper are running properly since I can do everything with out the authorizer class in the properties file. I tried to give root user on the broker machine all permisions on the cluster and that resulted in the same crash. Any help would be amazing and let me know if you need any further infromation.

Comment: Try setting `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` instead if you want to be able to connect remotely. Also, you don't need sudo